# Using semaphores to protect an array

Tags: java, multithreading, semaphore

Suppose that there are many threads that call the method `m(int i)` and change the value of the array in position `i`.  Is the following code correct, or is there a race condition?

```
public class A{
    private int []a =new int[N];
    private Semaphore[] s=new Semaphore[N];

    public A(){
        for(int i =0 ; i<N ; i++)
           s[i]=new Semaphore(1);
    }

    public void m(int i){
        s[i].acquire();
        a[i]++;
        s[i].release();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The code is correct, I see no race condition although both `a` and `s` should be made `final`.  You should also use a try/finally *every* time you use locks that need to be acquired and released:

```
s[i].acquire();
try {
   a[i]++;
} finally {
   s[i].release();
}
```

But, for updating an array, the idea of individual locks per item is very unnecessary.  A single lock would be just as appropriate since the major cost is the memory updating and the other native synchronization.  This said, if the actual operation is *not* a `int ++` then you are warranted in using a `Semaphore` or other `Lock` object.

But for simple operations, something like the following is fine:

```
// make sure it is final if you are synchronizing on it
private final int[] a = new int[N];
...

public void m(int i) {
   synchronized (a) {
      a[i]++:
   }
}
```

If you are really worried about the blocking then an array of `AtomicInteger` is another possibility but even this feels like overkill unless a profiler tells you otherwise.

```
private final AtomicInteger[] a = new AtomicInteger[N];
...

public A(){
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
       a[i] = new AtomicInteger(0);
}

public void m(int i) {
    a[i].incrementAndGet();
}
```

**Edit:**

I just wrote a [quick stupid test program](http://pastebin.com/xDiXEFP0) that compares a single `synchronized` lock, a `synchronized` on an array of locks, `AtomicInteger` array, and `Semaphore` array.  Here are the results:

- `synchronized` on the `int[]` 10617ms
- `synchronized` on an array of `Object[]` 1827ms
- `AtomicInteger` array 1414ms
- `Semaphore` array 3211ms

**But**, the kicker is that this is with **10 threads** each doing **10 million** iterations.  Sure it is faster but unless you are truly doing millions of iterations, you won't see any noticeable performance improvement in your application.  This is the definition of ["premature optimization"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Premature_optimization#When_to_optimize).  You *will* be paying for code complexity, increasing the likelihood of bugs, adding debugging time, increasing maintenance costs, etc..  To quote Knuth:

> We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Now, as the OP implies in comments, the `i++` is not the real operation that s/he is protecting.  If the increment is a lot more time consuming (i.e. if the blocking is increased), then the array of locks will be required.

Comment: The synchronization of "a" will create a bottleneck. An array of AtomicIntegers will not perform better than the question proposal but is absolutly more clean.

Comment: @JonathanBarbero Why do you think an array of AtomicIntegers will not perform better then the OP's suggestion?

Comment: You are missing the point @Jonathon.  _Any_ synchronization is going to be much more costly than the integer++.  My point is that putting one lock per array item is _not_ going to be buy you much if any speed.

Comment: @Gray If there are a lot of AtomicIntegers then putting a lock per item will certainly increase overall throughput.  Perfect example is CHM vs Hastable

Comment: If the real operation is more complex than an integer increment and you have a reasonably large number of objects in your array (or `List`), there's a middle ground between one-lock-for-all and one-lock-per-object, which is lock striping. [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) has a [nice implementation](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/index.html?com/google/common/util/concurrent/Striped.html) since release 13.

Comment: I can use only Semaphore and i have a problem(i'm studying for an university exam) ,a real-life situation like a supermarket with N cash desks . I can't lock all cash desks for only one payment .. Sorry for may bad English :)

Comment: I've added some performance stats to the end of my answer along with my overall point about performance in these cases.

Comment: @Gray Good call on performance stats.  Still not sure exactly what Jonathan was talking about as far as performance.

Comment: @Gray: as your test show the "synchronized" on a single object is not a good choice. The question is about many threads concurrently doing an operation. With the "synchronized" over a common object (an array in this case) it acts as a bottleneck. Maybe you could use "synchronized" on each array item, this will allow concurrent operation between distinct array positions.

Comment: You are completely missing the point @Jonathan.  Those results show that synchronizing on a common object takes 0.01 _nanoseconds_ versus 0.001 _nanoseconds_.  The cost of the code complexity is _much_ larger at those speeds unless you have literally 10s of millions of iterations.   Read up about the problems with premature optimization: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Premature_optimization#When_to_optimize

Comment: @Gray: sync on a common object you are solving a different problem, not the asked one. There are many threads working on different items and this strategy blocks them.